# What is the difference between (ㄴ/는)다지요? and (ㄴ/는)다면서요?

Tags: grammar, meaning

i have 2 sentences as follows:

> 민수 씨는 이번 시험에 1등을 **했다지요?**

and

> 민수 씨는 이번 시험에 1등을 **했다면서요?**

I wonder how these two structures are different? Can you help me to understand them? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are about the same in your examples.  I think 했다면서요 sounds slightly more informal, but the difference is negligible.

One minor thing is that -다면서요 has another usage while -다지요 (short for -다고 하지요) is used only in this one sense (but it can be used in both declarative and interrogative sense).

- 영철이는 과에서 여행을 **간다면서** 일찍 나갔어요. (간다면서 = 간다고 (말)하면서)
- 영철이는 아침 일찍 나갔어요. 과에서 여행을 **간다면서요**. (inverted)

Here, 다면서요 means that he went out *saying he was going on a school department trip*.  This is different from your example which means "I heard them (some people) saying that ...".

Comment: you have no idea how much you have helped me. Thank you very much!